# CSS Positioning with AddThis

Tags: html, css, html-table, addthis

I currently have a Table "solution" to formatting the AddThis Div Buttons.
You can see this at: http://www.siding4u.com/save-on-siding.php

At the top of the page it shows correctly:
[image: AddThis buttons formatted to the right of an image and offset at the top of the page]

Here's the Code (work around) for that:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="60%" align="right"><img title="Help us. Help you." src="http://www.siding4u.com/media/shareaholic/img_help-us-help-you_right_yellow-text.png" alt="TEXT: Sharing is caring! Help us. Help you." width="360" height="23" /></td>
    <td width="40%" align="left"><!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=siding4u"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END --></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm having/wanting to convert all of my table layouts to CSS but I can't seem to get the AddThis buttons to cooperate.  They always seem to "LEFT JUSTIFY" or BREAK Somehow - no matter what I try.

I'm guessing this is an easy fix but I'm one of those CSS "block heads" that can't seem to whip the CSS into shape.

Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In css aligning images is based on their position on the page rather than their justification ( the elements with class `addthis_button_preferred_1...n` should probably control this ) In a table you justify it left/center/right etc. while with CSS your aim is to align the  in a way that it's child elements will be in the middle.

**HTML:**

```
<div id='wrapper'> <!-- parent div containing the help-us-help-you image and the buttons-->
    <div id="help_us"><!-- float:left because we want the image div and the button dive to be besides eachother -->
        <img title="Help us. Help you." src="http://www.siding4u.com/media/shareaholic/img_help-us-help-you_right_yellow-text.png" alt="TEXT: Sharing is caring! Help us. Help you." width="360" height="23"/>
    </div>
    <div id='buttons'><!-- this div should also be floated left and have padding, to align the buttons correctly -->

        <!-- each of the link elements should get some padding -->
        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1 button_preferred"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2 button_preferred"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3 button_preferred"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4 button_preferred"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_compact button_preferred"></a>
        <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style button_preferred"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The whole example is online [on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3ks9/), and should hopefully help with the alignment, and is a pure CSS solution, no tables there at all!

p.s. As a side note, I do recomend you use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for CSS/HTML/javascript issues, it does help us see the problem better, and make changes faster.

**EDIT**
For the second issue:

```
<div align="center" style="margin-bottom:0; margin-top:5px;"> 
<div id='wrapper'> 
...
​</div>
...
</div>
```

For this element the height for some reason is 48 px, which creates a gap between the two elements. So apply a height to it, change:

`style="margin-bottom:0; margin-top:5px;"`

**TO:**

`style="margin-bottom:0; margin-top:5px;height:23px;"`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!
Thank you for the jsfiddle recommendation... I will use that.  If the effort to help others, I'll continue here to a complete solution to hopefully help others who might be having this type of an issue.

I am having one issue with it.  I created a demo page: [link](http://www.siding4u.com/_DEMO_header_2012-07-13.php) 
THE ISSUE: No matter what I do I can't seem to get rid of a large space between the wrapper div and the rest of the content.
Ref. image: [link](https://plus.google.com/photos/105387763531004182740/albums/5765087861976293505?authkey=COXI9K6ov53ItAE)

Comment: @Rob Hello rob, can you please past the CSS and HTML for the page ? Im guessing it's a spacing issue (something along the lines of the below div is set to be 50px down from the top)

Comment: @ Lyuben - I'm not sure where to provide that... this comment area only allows like 600 characters.  The link shows the whole doc with code and everything.  Here it is again: http://www.siding4u.com/_DEMO_header_2012-07-13.php

Comment: @Rob look at the edit in the answer above, and you can add code/text by editing your answer.

Comment: That Was IT!!!  Awesome!!!  How did you arrive at that conclusion?  Did you use a utility of some type?

Comment: @Rob Thanks to chrome's dev tools. (although all browsers have developer tools) I right-clicked on the windows and then selected "Inspect Element" and started navigating through the HTML structure of the page, got to the div and chrome dev-tools tells you all the CSS style applied to the divs.

Comment: Awesome Tip, thank you!!!  It's all there in Chrome's dev tools.  I see now that AddThis has a bunch of "!important" CSS attributes and such.  Thanks again Lyuben!!!